# ggparcoord() from ggally in R produces Warning: The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation: colour

Tags: r, ggally

The Warning "
The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation: colour" appears when using ggparcoord() from GGally package in R. I don't know why and how to avoid?

```
#dataset2----

data2 <- data.frame(
  "geneSymbol" = paste("Gene", 1:10),
  "condition1" = rnorm(10, 3, 1),
  "condition2" = rnorm(10, 4, 0.5),
  "condition3" = rnorm(10, 7, 0.3)
  )

ggparcoord(
  data = data2,
  columns = 2:4,
  groupColumn = 1,
  scale = "std",
  scaleSummary = "mean",
  centerObsID = 1,
  missing = "exclude",
  showPoints = FALSE,
  splineFactor = FALSE,
  alphaLines = 1,
  boxplot = TRUE,
  shadeBox = NULL,
  mapping = aes(labels = 1),
  title = "TEST"
)
```

> sessionInfo()
> R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.utf8  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.utf8    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.utf8

time zone: Europe/Berlin
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] ggrepel_0.9.3    GGally_2.1.2     readxl_1.4.3     openxlsx_4.2.5.2 lubridate_1.9.2
[6] forcats_1.0.0    stringr_1.5.0    dplyr_1.1.2      purrr_1.0.1      readr_2.1.4
[11] tidyr_1.3.0      tibble_3.2.1     ggplot2_3.4.2    tidyverse_2.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] utf8_1.2.3           generics_0.1.3       futile.options_1.0.1 stringi_1.7.12
[5] hms_1.1.3            magrittr_2.0.3       grid_4.3.1           timechange_0.2.0
[9] RColorBrewer_1.1-3   cellranger_1.1.0     plyr_1.8.8           zip_2.3.0
[13] reshape_0.8.9        formatR_1.14         gridExtra_2.3        fansi_1.0.4
[17] scales_1.2.1         ggfortify_0.4.16     cli_3.6.1            rlang_1.1.1
[21] futile.logger_1.4.3  munsell_0.5.0        withr_2.5.0          tools_4.3.1
[25] tzdb_0.4.0           colorspace_2.1-0     lambda.r_1.2.4       ggvenn_0.1.10
[29] vctrs_0.6.3          R6_2.5.1             lifecycle_1.0.3      pkgconfig_2.0.3
[33] pillar_1.9.0         gtable_0.3.3         glue_1.6.2           Rcpp_1.0.11
[37] tidyselect_1.2.0     rstudioapi_0.15.0    farver_2.1.1         labeling_0.4.2
[41] VennDiagram_1.7.3    compiler_4.3.1

Comment: While annoying I think that should not be a big deal. It's just a warning and the plot looks fine. The warning most likely results from a change introduced with `ggplot2 3.4.0` (see e.g. https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5053 for a related issue), which is most likely not accounted for in the released version of `GGAlly` (which is from June 2021).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to `boxplot = TRUE`, but as long as you do not care about the color of the boxplots, you can ignore it.